# When i run in Notepad++ its giving me error Xrm is undefined.Can anyone help please

Tags: notepad++, dynamics-crm-2013

```
function Page__onload()
{
}

if( Xrm.Page.getAttribute("new_project").getValue()!=null){
    Xrm.Page.getAttribute("new_proj").setValue(Xrm.Page.getAttribute
    ("new_project").getValue());
}

function ProjectNumber()
{
    if( Xrm.Page.getAttribute("new_projectnumber").getValue()!=null)
    {
        Xrm.Page.getAttribute("new_projnum").setValue(Xrm.Page.getAttribute
        ("new_projectnumber").getValue().toString());
    }

    else{
        return error;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not exactly sure what you mean when you say run in Notepad++ but you need fix your first function:

```
function Page__onload()
{    
    if( Xrm.Page.getAttribute("new_project").getValue()!=null){
        Xrm.Page.getAttribute("new_proj").setValue(Xrm.Page.getAttribute
        ("new_project").getValue());
    }
}
```